# Spray.io support Typed Actors and UnTyped Actors?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, spray, spray-routing

Recently I came across a question where somebody asked =>

"**Does Spray support Typed Actors or Untyped Actors ?** "

Can somebody help me in understanding that?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: spray is obsolete and became part of Akka. It's now called akka-streams and akka-http.

Comment: Thats fine , but we are  still using Spray 1.3.3 version , so wanted to know if anybody knows what type of Actors Spray support?

Comment: Spray is built using untyped actors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.